# How to understand a periodicity in the training loss using a pre-trained model of PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, pre-trained-model, image-classification, sgd, trainingloss

I'm using a pre-trained model from Pytorch ( Resnet 18,34,50) in order to classify images. During the training, a weird periodicity appears in the training as you can see in the image below. Did somebody already have a similar issue?In order to deal with the overfitting, I'm using Data augmentation in the preprocessing.
When using SGD as an optimizer with the following parameters, we obtain this sort of graph:

- criterion: NLLLoss()
- learning rate: 0.0001
- epoch: 40
- print every 40 iteration

[image: SGD Training vs Validation loss]

We also try adam and Adam bound as optimizers but the same periodicity was observed.

Thank's in advance for your answer!

Here is the code :

```
def train_classifier():
    start=0
    stop=0
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    epochs = 40
    steps = 0
    print_every = 40

    model.to('cuda')
    epo=[]
    train=[]
    valid=[]
    acc_valid=[]
    for e in range(epochs):
        print('Currently running epoch',e,':')
        model.train()
    
        running_loss = 0
    
        for images, labels in iter(train_loader):
        
            steps += 1
        
            images, labels = images.to('cuda'), labels.to('cuda')
        
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        
            output = model.forward(images)
            loss = criterion(output, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        
            running_loss += loss.item()
        
            if steps % print_every == 0:
                
                model.eval()
                
                # Turn off gradients for validation, saves memory and computations
                with torch.no_grad():
                    validation_loss, accuracy = validation(model, val_loader, criterion)
            
                print("Epoch: {}/{}.. ".format(e+1, epochs),
                      "Training Loss: {:.3f}.. ".format(running_loss/print_every),
                      "Validation Loss: {:.3f}.. ".format(validation_loss/len(val_loader)),
                      "Validation Accuracy: {:.3f}".format(accuracy/len(val_loader)))
                stop = timeit.default_timer()
                print('Time: ', stop - start)
                acc_valid.append(accuracy/len(val_loader))
                train.append(running_loss/print_every)
                valid.append(validation_loss/len(val_loader))
                epo.append(e+1)
                running_loss = 0
                model.train()
    return train,epo,valid,acc_valid
```

Comment: Are the images you're training on a subset of those used to pre-train resnet itself?

Comment: Are you sure it's not an issue with the code? Perhaps you're accumulating some losses incorrectly?

Comment: @iacob No the image are scans of aggregates made in a lab so they weren't used to pre-train the resnet

Comment: Assuming `epo` is what you plot in the x-axis, shouldn't you have `epo.append(steps)` instead, since you save the loss once per step, and not per epoch?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thank's for you help !
So for the plot I use :
plt.plot(train, color='blue', marker='o', linewidth=2) 
plt.plot(valid, color='red', marker='o', linewidth=2)
So I don't think that epo will be the issue

Comment: Ok, then I don't see any clear issue. One possibility is, since you are plotting the average loss of groups of 40 images, and not the entire dataset, it is possible that your loader loads data in an order where the initial images are somehow easier to classify. This could cause lower loss instances to be present early in an epoch, and higher loss instances to appear later. Have you enabled shuffling in your train loader?

Comment: Plotting the loss per epoch may be more meaningful, btw, since it covers the entire dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I will try your suggestion